How should I use Flutter to implement the UWB function on an iPhone to transmit messages?
I want to use Flutter to implement the UWB (Ultra-Wideband) function on an iPhone to transmit messages. However, I am facing some difficulties and need guidance on how to proceed.
I tried looking into Flutter packages and iOS UWB APIs, hoping to find a straightforward way to integrate UWB functionality. I expected to find some packages or plugins that support UWB communication or at least some guidance on how to bridge native iOS functionality with Flutter. Unfortunately, I have not found sufficient resources or examples that address this specific use case.
Hope someone can provide me with direction or practical examples to help me better implement the functionality. I would greatly appreciate it if anyone is willing to assist.
